# Trim field values based on field in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a set of entries in `Table1`

```
Field1 
------
aaa111 
aaa222 
bbb333
```

And I have another table - `Prefixes`:

```
Prefix
------
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I want output to look like this:

```
Output
------
111
222
333
```

Aka, if any of the `Field1` in `Table1` starts with something in `Prefixes` , trim that part. I can create `cursor` and do `like` comparison, but I wonder whether there is a simpler solution?

Note: prefixes are not necessarily 3 characters and no overlaps in prefixes

Comment: In sql you should never use a cursor if you can avoid it.  Instead you need to think in SQL -- aka sets.  For a good example this see Gordan's answer.

Comment: @Hogan , yep. That's why asked, can't come with anything except cursor myself

Comment: Can there be overlapping prefixes, e.g. `'aa'`, `'aaa'` and `'aaa1'`? What would the expected results be for `'aaa111'` against those prefixes?

Comment: @HABO, no overlaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use `left join`:

```
select coalesce(stuff(t1.field1, 1, len(p.prefix), ''), t1.field1) as new_field1
from table1 t1 left join
     prefixes p
     on t1.field1 like p.prefix + '%';
```

This will not be efficient.  SQL Server has to do a nested-loop join, cycling through all the prefixes.  This also assumes that the prefixes are a "disjoint" set in the sense that at most one would match.

If multiple prefixes could match, you would need to explain how to choose the appropriate one.

Comment: you could also join on `left(t1.field1, len(p.prefix)) = p.prefix` probably faster

Comment: Note to self: don't post answers from cellphone.